# JMeter jp@gc-WebDriver Sampler Element dynamic name on XML Button

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using the JMeter with Groovy for developing the Client side scripts. I am not sure how to given the name for below dynamic element variable. Please kindly advise.

findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[30]")).click();

I have tried below element name but didn't work.
[error] Implicit Wait timed out after 10000ms
[error] Element //div[contains(@class,'el-button--')]/li/div not found

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1dK9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr2Cc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcv33.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Locate the [`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) element with text `OK`
2. Locate its [parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/parent) - it will be the [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) you're looking for

Something like:

```
findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'OK')]/parent::button")).click()
```

If there is more than one span with text OK you will have to figure out the way to uniquely identify the particular button you want to click.

You may find [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) article useful, it's mainly for JMeter's XPath Extractor, but the syntax will be the same for the WebDriver Sampler when it comes to XPath language evaluation.